# XPath 1.0 check count

Tags: xml, xpath, count, nodes

I have the following XML document :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE inventory SYSTEM "books.dtd">
<inventory>
    <book num="b1">
        <title>Snow Crash</title>
        <author>Neal Stephenson</author>
        <publisher>Spectra</publisher>
        <price>14.95</price>
        <chapter>
            <title>Snow Crash - Chapter A</title>
            <paragraph>
                This is the <emph>first</emph> paragraph.
                <image file="firstParagraphImage.gif"/>
                afetr image...
            </paragraph>
            <paragraph>
                This is the <emph>second</emph> paragraph.
                <image file="secondParagraphImage.gif"/>
                afetr image...
            </paragraph>
        </chapter>
        <chapter>
            <title>Snow Crash - Chapter B</title>
            <section>
                <title>Chapter B - section 1</title>
                <paragraph>
                    This is the <emph>first</emph> paragraph of section 1 in chapter B.
                    <image file="Chapter_B_firstParagraphImage.gif"/>
                    afetr image...
                </paragraph>
                <paragraph>
                    This is the <emph>second</emph> paragraph of section 1 in chapter B.
                    <image file="Chapter_B_secondParagraphImage.gif"/>
                    afetr image...
                </paragraph>
            </section>
        </chapter>
        <chapter>
            <title>Chapter C</title>
            <paragraph>
                This chapter has no images and only one paragraph
            </paragraph>
        </chapter>
    </book>
    <book num="b2">
        <title>Burning Tower</title>
        <author>Larry Niven</author>
        <author>Jerry Pournelle</author>
        <publisher>Pocket</publisher>
        <price>5.99</price>
        <chapter>
            <title>Burning Tower - Chapter A</title>
        </chapter>
        <chapter>
            <title>Burning Tower - Chapter B</title>
            <paragraph>
                This is the <emph>second</emph> paragraph of chapter B in the 2nd book.
                <image file="Burning_Tower_Chapter_B_secondParagraphImage.gif"/>
                afetr image...
            </paragraph>
        </chapter>
    </book>
    <book num="b3">
        <title>Zodiac</title>
        <author>Neal Stephenson</author>
        <publisher>Spectra</publisher>
        <price>7.50</price>
        <chapter>
            <title>Zodiac - Chapter A</title>
        </chapter>
    </book>
    <!-- more books... -->
</inventory>
```

How to write an XPath 1.0 expression to select all books that have more then 1 image?

I tried `inventory/book//image[2]/ancestor::book` but it give wrong result ...

is `inventory/book//image[2]` give all the 2nd image in every book ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/book[(.//image)[2]]
```

**This selects all `book` elements that are children of the top element of the XML document and that have a second `image` descendant**.

**This expression is evaluated potentially faster** than any expression starting with `//`, because an expression starting with `//` typically causes the whole document to be traversed.

**It is also more efficient than**:

```
//book[count(.//image)>1]
```

even if this expression was re-written not to start with `//`.

This is so, because in the above expression `count(.//image)` causes all `image` descendants to be counted, while in our solution:

```
(.//image)[2]
```

only verifies that a second `image` descendant exists.

**Finally, here is an XSLT - based verification:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy-of select="/*/book[(.//image)[2]]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied to the provided XML document:**

```
<inventory>
        <book num="b1">
            <title>Snow Crash</title>
            <author>Neal Stephenson</author>
            <publisher>Spectra</publisher>
            <price>14.95</price>
            <chapter>
                <title>Snow Crash - Chapter A</title>
                <paragraph>
                    This is the <emph>first</emph> paragraph.
                    <image file="firstParagraphImage.gif"/>
                    afetr image...
                </paragraph>
                <paragraph>
                    This is the <emph>second</emph> paragraph.
                    <image file="secondParagraphImage.gif"/>
                    afetr image...
                </paragraph>
            </chapter>
            <chapter>
                <title>Snow Crash - Chapter B</title>
                <section>
                    <title>Chapter B - section 1</title>
                    <paragraph>
                        This is the <emph>first</emph> paragraph of section 1 in chapter B.
                        <image file="Chapter_B_firstParagraphImage.gif"/>
                        afetr image...
                    </paragraph>
                    <paragraph>
                        This is the <emph>second</emph> paragraph of section 1 in chapter B.
                        <image file="Chapter_B_secondParagraphImage.gif"/>
                        afetr image...
                    </paragraph>
                </section>
            </chapter>
            <chapter>
                <title>Chapter C</title>
                <paragraph>
                    This chapter has no images and only one paragraph
                </paragraph>
            </chapter>
        </book>
        <book num="b2">
            <title>Burning Tower</title>
            <author>Larry Niven</author>
            <author>Jerry Pournelle</author>
            <publisher>Pocket</publisher>
            <price>5.99</price>
            <chapter>
                <title>Burning Tower - Chapter A</title>
            </chapter>
            <chapter>
                <title>Burning Tower - Chapter B</title>
                <paragraph>
                    This is the <emph>second</emph> paragraph of chapter B in the 2nd book.
                    <image file="Burning_Tower_Chapter_B_secondParagraphImage.gif"/>
                    afetr image...
                </paragraph>
            </chapter>
        </book>
        <book num="b3">
            <title>Zodiac</title>
            <author>Neal Stephenson</author>
            <publisher>Spectra</publisher>
            <price>7.50</price>
            <chapter>
                <title>Zodiac - Chapter A</title>
            </chapter>
        </book>
        <!-- more books... -->
</inventory>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the selected nodes (in this case just one) are copied to the output**:

```
<book num="b1">
   <title>Snow Crash</title>
   <author>Neal Stephenson</author>
   <publisher>Spectra</publisher>
   <price>14.95</price>
   <chapter>
      <title>Snow Crash - Chapter A</title>
      <paragraph>
                    This is the <emph>first</emph> paragraph.
                    <image file="firstParagraphImage.gif"/>
                    afetr image...
                </paragraph>
      <paragraph>
                    This is the <emph>second</emph> paragraph.
                    <image file="secondParagraphImage.gif"/>
                    afetr image...
                </paragraph>
   </chapter>
   <chapter>
      <title>Snow Crash - Chapter B</title>
      <section>
         <title>Chapter B - section 1</title>
         <paragraph>
                        This is the <emph>first</emph> paragraph of section 1 in chapter B.
                        <image file="Chapter_B_firstParagraphImage.gif"/>
                        afetr image...
                    </paragraph>
         <paragraph>
                        This is the <emph>second</emph> paragraph of section 1 in chapter B.
                        <image file="Chapter_B_secondParagraphImage.gif"/>
                        afetr image...
                    </paragraph>
      </section>
   </chapter>
   <chapter>
      <title>Chapter C</title>
      <paragraph>
                    This chapter has no images and only one paragraph
                </paragraph>
   </chapter>
</book>
```

Answer (score 4):

try with this

```
//book[count(.//image)>1]
```

all books that have more than one image tag somewhere

Answer (score 3):

`inventory/book//image[2]/` gets you the second image provided there are 2 or more `image` child nodes in your `book` element. Try:

```
   //inventory/book[count(descendant::image) > 1]
```

You need to move down the hierarchy to a `book` element and then start your query from there on. The predicate (or query in layman terms) is to look for all `image` elements from there on -- which is exactly what the `descendant` axis does. You append `::` and `nodename` to select a particular descendant as we do with `descendant::image` to look for all `image`s. The final test if to make sure if the `count` (as the name of the function suggests) is greater than 1 or not.